# Autocomplete Case Sensitive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way for the material-ui Autocomplete react component to not be case sensitive?

For example, if I have a list item "Movies" I want to be able to search "movies", "MOVIES", "Movies", etc. and have it come up regardless of what letters are capitalized in the search.

Comment: The demos I just tried at https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete appear to be case insensitive e.g. `return` and `RETURN` both return the same two movies in the first example

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick. ignoreCase defaults to true. Lowercase everything.

```
import { createFilterOptions } from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
  ignoreCase: true,
});

<Autocomplete filterOptions={filterOptions} />
```

For more information, check out [Custom filter](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#custom-filter).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is from the answer before but you should make the ignoreCase: false

```
const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
  ignoreCase: false,
});
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33541216)